# How can I get the shuffler method to only shuffle certain indexes in an array? While not shuffling indexes which I want to stay the same

Tags: java, arrays, char, shuffle

My problem is as follows:

```
    char [] letters = {' ', 'a', ' ', 'b', ' ', 'c'};

    for(int i = 0; i < letters.length; i ++) {
        int random = (int) (Math.random()* letters.length);

        char temp = letters[i];
        letters [i] = letters [random];
        letters [random] = temp;

    }
```

This method shuffles the array, very good; however I would like the both the shuffle method and the Math.random method to ignore the spaces and only shuffle indexes that have a letter value. To further explain: I would like the output of the letters array to have all the spaces at the same index as they were originally, while only allowing indexes that contained a letter to be swapped. So an example of a random acceptable out put of the letters array after it goes through this method would look something like this:

[ ' ', 'b', ' ', 'c', ' ', 'a' ]

or maybe even

[ ' ', 'c', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'b' ]

any help on how I can accomplish this would be just absolutely fantastic... I have tried every variation of for, while, and if loops trying to constrict the boundaries of the Math.random method to just indexes that contain a letter, and same for the for loop, but I have come up with nothing. It has me beat. Thank you very much in advance to anyone who could help me out and explain a little.

Comment: I'd try to extract the elements that should be shuffled and keep track of their original indices (e.g. 0->1, 1->3, 2->5 meaning that the element at index 0 originally was at index 1 etc.) Then you could shuffle that (sub) array and in the end set the elements in the orginal array according to their original index (so the element at index 0 of the shuffled array would be set at index 1 in the original array etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply skip the whitespace indices:

```
char [] letters = {' ', 'a', ' ', 'b', ' ', 'c'};

for(int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    int random = (int) (Math.random()* letters.length);

    if (letters[random] == ' ' || letters[i] == ' ') continue; // here

    char temp = letters[i];
    letters [i] = letters [random];
    letters [random] = temp;
}
```

Comment: Please accept this answer if it solved your problem. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following logic :

```
char[] letters = { ' ', 'a', ' ', 'b', ' ', 'c', ' ', 'd' };

for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    int random = (int) (Math.random() * letters.length);

    // observe this
    if (!Character.isWhitespace(letters[random]) && !Character.isWhitespace(letters[i])) { 
        char temp = letters[i];
        letters[i] = letters[random];
        letters[random] = temp;
    }

}
```

Explanation :

- You can add a simple `if` condition to check whether both elements (i.e `letters[random]` and `letters[i]`) to be swapped are not *whitespaces*.